# Folder res/raw adding mp3?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android project with API21. In the tree of this project in `res` didn't exist the folder `raw`. I created this folder `raw` to add mp3 files but when I try `R.raw.bip` the autocomplete of Eclipse Luna not display this path. 
In my project I'm importing `import br.com.myproject.myapp.R;`

I did refresh, I did close/open and still doesn't works.

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

Instead to add raw folder in my project Eclipse I added folder in windows explorer>myproject>res>raw. Now works.